# phpMailer mass mailing script

Tags: php, email

I'm working on a script that will be able to send mass e-mails. I'm using cron to run this script. I'm fetching e-mails from queue.

I need to ensure that:

1. To one e-mail will NEVER be sent more than one message (it could be executed more than once)
2. One e-mail must have only one recipient (not multiple to)
3. It must to jump over non existing e-mail addresses

Please, can you help me to improve this script? I need to find hidden bugs in this code.

```
try {
    $logger = new Logger(BASE_DIR . '/log/');

    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    // Fetch queue + create lock for update
    $sql = 'SELECT mq.`mail_queue_id`,
    mq.`to`, 
    mq.`priority`, 
    mb.`from`, 
    mb.`reply_to`, 
    mb.`alias`,
    mb.`subject`,
    mb.`message`
    FROM mail_queue mq
    JOIN mailer_batch mb ON mq.`mailer_batch_id` = mb.`mailer_batch_id`
    WHERE mq.`mail_status_id` = 2 
    ORDER BY mq.`priority` DESC, mq.`created` ASC 
    LIMIT ' . BATCH_SIZE . ' FOR UPDATE;';
    $sth2 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth2->execute();
    $queue = $sth2->fetchAll();

    if (count($queue) > 0) {
        // Fetch active SMTP data
        $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `smtp_server` WHERE `active` = 1 LIMIT 1;");
        $sth1->execute();
        $smtpData = $sth1->fetch();
        if ($smtpData === false) {
            throw new Exception("There is no active SMTP server.");
        }

        $smtp = new SmtpServer($smtpData['host'], $smtpData['port'], $smtpData['auth'], $smtpData['username'], $smtpData['password'], $smtpData['secure']);
    }

    // Send it
    foreach ($queue as $row) {

        $csvArray = array();

        // Fetch all params
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM mail_param WHERE mail_queue_id = ' . $row['mail_queue_id'] . ';';
        $sth3 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth3->execute();
        $params = $sth3->fetchAll();

        $paramArray = array();
        foreach ($params as $param) {
            $paramArray[$param['param_key']] = $param['param_value'];
        }

        if (count($paramArray) > 0) {
            $csvArray[$row['to']] = $paramArray;
        }

        // Create mail template
        $mailTemplate = new MailTemplate($row['from'], $row['alias'], $row['subject'], $row['message'], $row['reply_to']);
        $mailTemplate->applyParameters($csvArray);

        try {
            $res = $smtp->send($row['to'], $mailTemplate);

            // Update state (3 = sent, 4 = sending error)
            if ($res) {
                $sql = 'UPDATE mail_queue
                        SET mail_status_id = 3
                        WHERE mail_queue_id = ' . $row['mail_queue_id'] . ';';
            } else {
                $sql = 'UPDATE mail_queue
                        SET mail_status_id = 4
                        WHERE mail_queue_id = ' . $row['mail_queue_id'] . ';';
                $logger->log('E-mail pro "' . $row['to'] . '" se nepodařilo odeslat.');
            }
            $sth4 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth4->execute();

        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            $logger->log($e->getMessage(), $logger::WARNING);
            $sql = 'UPDATE mail_queue
                SET mail_status_id = 4
                WHERE mail_queue_id = ' . $row['mail_queue_id'] . ';';
            $sth5 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $sth5->execute();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

    }

    $dbh->commit();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $logger->log($e->getMessage(), $logger::ERROR);
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $logger->log($e->getMessage(), $logger::ERROR);
    $dbh->commit();
}
```

And SmtpServer->send() method:

```
public function send($emailRecipient, MailTemplate $mailTemplate)
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mailer->isSMTP();
    $mailer->SMTPKeepAlive = false;
    $mailer->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mailer->Debugoutput = 'html';

    $mailer->Host = $this->getHost();
    $mailer->Port = $this->getPort();

    // SMTP auth
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = $this->getSmtpAuth();
    if ($this->getSmtpAuth()) {
        $mailer->SMTPSecure = $this->getSecure();
        $mailer->Username = $this->getUsername();
        $mailer->Password = $this->getPassword();
    }

    // Set ReplyTo
    $replyTo = $mailTemplate->getReplyTo();
    if ($replyTo != "") {
        $mailer->AddReplyTo($replyTo, $mailTemplate->getAlias());
    }

    // From and alias
    $mailer->setFrom($mailTemplate->getFrom(), $mailTemplate->getAlias());

    $isMessageHtml = $mailTemplate->isMessageHtml();

    $mailer->Subject = $mailTemplate->getSubject($emailRecipient);
    $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    // HTML or plain text body
    if ($isMessageHtml) {
        $mailer->msgHTML($mailTemplate->getMessage($emailRecipient), dirname(__FILE__));
    } else {
        $mailer->isHTML(false);
        $mailer->Body = $mailTemplate->getMessage($emailRecipient);
    }

    // To
    $mailer->addAddress($emailRecipient);

    if ($mailer->send()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

In the past I had some serious issues with multiple "To" in one e-mail; this is why I reconnect after sending each e-mail. I think `ClearAllRecipients()` and other Clears function are not safe enough and reconnecting after sending one e-mail is much more safer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete review, just a couple of points I noticed. I didn't see any bugs, but I didn't test the code in-depth.

**Security**

You should use prepared statements even if the data comes from the database (like with `$row['mail_queue_id']` and `$row['to']`. Otherwise, you might be vulnerable to [second order SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_Order_SQL_Injection). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952187/how-do-i-demonstrate-a-second-order-sql-injection).

**`if (cond) return true; else return false;`**

```
if ($mailer->send()) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
return $mailer->send();
```

**Duplicate Code**

```
        $sql = 'UPDATE mail_queue
            SET mail_status_id = [id]
            WHERE mail_queue_id = ' . $row['mail_queue_id'] . ';';
        $sth5 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth5->execute();
```

You have this code 3 times, I would either extract it to it's own function (`updateMailQeue(errorCode)`), or just save the error code in a local variable and execute this code at the end.

**Confusing Check**

You have this check:

```
if (count($queue) > 0) {
   // prepare smtp server
}
// do stuff with the smtp server
```

For a second, it confused be why only part of the code is inside this check (the answer is obviously that the `foreach` is an implicit check itself). I would rewrite it like this:

```
if (count($queue) > 0) {
   return; // nothing to send
}
// prepare smtp server
// do stuff with the smtp server
```

If you at some point extend the code, your code could easier lead to bugs.

**Length of first Code Block**

Your first try block is too long and too deeply nested. You could extract the code for each individual row in a new function (for example `sendMail(mail_id)`).